# I used sed to change a word, the file is now erased

Tags: sed

I was to use the sed command to change CIS132 to CIS132 Introduction to Unix/Linux.
I did:

```
sed 's/CIS132/CIS132 Introduction to Unix\/Linux/g' CISed
```

I got a command prompt so I figured all set. I then cat CISed and got no output. What happened there?
Can I get the contents back that I somehow erased?

Thanks

Jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you did this:

```
sed 's/CIS132/CIS132 Introduction to Unix\/Linux/g' CISed > CISed
```

.. and that's not the way to make a replacement `--in-place`. The correct way is:

```
sed --in-place 's/CIS132/CIS132 Introduction to Unix\/Linux/g' CISed
```

---

- What happened there?

You redirect the standard output to a *new empty* file called *CISed* (you used `>`). It erases any content in the file.

- Can I get the contents back that I somehow erased?

You can't. You simply replaced it with an empty file.

---

*Extracted from your comment:*

This is your shell history:

```
971 cat CISed
972 grep 'CIS132' | sed 's/CIS132/CIS132 Introduction to Unix/Linus/g' CISed
973 sed '1,2s/CIS132/CIS132 Introduction to Unix/Linus/g' CISed
974 sed '1,3s/CIS132/CIS132 Introduction to Unix"/"Linus/g' CISed
975 sed 's/CIS132/CIS132 Introduction to Unix/Linux/g' > CISed
976 sed 's/CIS132/CIS132 Introduction to Unix/Linux/g' CISed
977 sed 's/CIS132/CIS132 Introduction to Unix'/'Linux/g' CISed
978 sed 's/CIS132/CIS132 Introduction to Unix\/Linux/g' CISed
979 cat CISed
980 cat CISed
981 ls
982 cat CISed
```

In **971** you read the content and it was there. Then, in **975** though the command fails, the redirection operator (`>`) creates a *new empty* file called `CISed` and that's the moment when your file is erased.

Comment: If you didn't redirect nor used --in-place and the command didn't print anything in the standard output, it only means that the file was empty before hand. Could you post the shell history? Maybe we can help you with this.

Comment: 971  cat CISed
  972  grep 'CIS132' | sed 's/CIS132/CIS132 Introduction to Unix/Linus/g' CISed
  973  sed '1,2s/CIS132/CIS132 Introduction to Unix/Linus/g' CISed
  974  sed '1,3s/CIS132/CIS132 Introduction to Unix"/"Linus/g' CISed
  975  sed 's/CIS132/CIS132 Introduction to Unix/Linux/g' > CISed
  976  sed 's/CIS132/CIS132 Introduction to Unix/Linux/g' CISed
  977  sed 's/CIS132/CIS132 Introduction to Unix'/'Linux/g' CISed
  978  sed 's/CIS132/CIS132 Introduction to Unix\/Linux/g' CISed
  979  cat CISed
  980  cat CISed
  981  ls
  982  cat CISed
971 is where I read it.I got error except 978